# Ubuntu SDK unable to play scope

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, scopes

I've just created a Unity Scope project in Ubuntu SDK. 
However I'm not able to run it, If I target the Desktop, I have the following error :

```
Starting /usr/ubuntu-sdk-ide/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_desktop_scoperunner.py...
ScopeRunner> Setting up environment
ScopeRunner> TmpDir:      /home/bertrand/.local/share/unity-scopes/unconfined/stars.kramp/
ScopeRunner> AppId:       stars.kramp_stars
Debug-helper> Environment initialized, starting the application
Debug-helper> Executing /usr/bin/unity-scope-tool /home/bertrand/dev/uapp/build-stars-Desktop-Default/src/stars.kramp_stars.ini
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

My desktop kit configuration is below : 
[image]

And I've also tried on with an emulator target, then I've another error :

```
Results:
Fatal error: /tmp/stars.kramp_0.1_armhf.click failed to install.
WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /tmp/stars.kramp_0.1_armhf.click: Framework "ubuntu-sdk-15.04.4" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)

Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed
```

My armhf kit configuration is below : 
[image]

I'm new to QT/UbuntuPhone/Click/Kit/Framework/target/andSoOn development environment, so I'd like to understand what's wrong.

I'm under ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to run on the Desktop target now. I've installed `qt5-defaul` and then configured the QT version in the Desktop target.

Not tried with the emulator but the Desktop is sufficient to develop